# Delete rows based on the multiple values as fast as possible

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consist a column named Url. There are around 500K Urls. I want to delete all the rows where the Urls consist of some domain name like amazon.com, ebay.com, bestbuy.com and so on.

Those Urls can be like the below:

https://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Water-Pumps-Sump-Pumps-Submersible-Sump-Pumps/N-5yc1vZbqj6

https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/ba/ba1bd2c2-82ea-4510-85c8-333392e70a23.pdf

https://us.amazon.com/Simer-A5000-Hole-Battery-System/dp/B000DZKXC2

[https://www.amazon.com/Hydromatic-DPS41-Diaphragm-Switch-Range/dp/B009S0NS0C](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009S0NS0C)

So the domain can be present as subdomain too. It may or may not consist with http, https, www, top level country domain name like co.uk, .co.nz and so on.

So I need an universal solution to delete any URL when the domain name is present in the exclude-sites list.

I already created a function for it which is working fine for smaller data set. But it couldn't clean the data for the 500K rows even after running it for straight 5 hours.

Here is the function I am using:

```
exclude_sites=['amazon.com','amzn.to','ebay.com','walmart.com','sears.com','costco.com','youtube.com', 'lowes.com', 'homedepot.com', 'bestbuy.com']

def exclude_urls(exclude_sites, df):
    i=[]
    
    for row in df['Url']:
        if any(url in row for url in exclude_sites):
             i.extend(df.index[df['Url']==row])
            #reset index  
        
    return i

df = df.drop(list( exclude_urls(exclude_sites, df)))
```

What might be the fastest solution to delete the domain saved on the exclude_sites list? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exclude_sites_escaped = [x.replace('.', '\.') for x in exclude_sites]
df[~df['Url'].str.contains('|'.join(exclude_sites_escaped), regex = True)]
```

Comment: This is not working. May be I have to trim the URL to domain first.

Comment: If you use the right regex you won't have to trim the data columns.

Comment: Adjusted the answer by stripping the domain. Unfortunately I'm not well versed in regex, maybe someone will point out how to do this without stripping

Comment: Just checked that it also deleted the below URL which is the domain saved the exclude_sites list:

http://www.ithazhtntr.media/kz7oc4f/sump-pump-alarm-amazon.html

How to deal with such scenarios?

Comment: Adjusted the answer to escape dot (since it's a special character in regex) instead of stripping. Now it should work for the case you mentioned.

Comment: It will be an exact match though, and it seems that's not exactly what you want, but at this point the question is purely about regex, so you should either post a new question or reformulate this one and adjust the tags

Comment: I have tested the code again. But I think I failed to make you understand my query. I only want to delete those rows where the URL consist the domain name I saved in the exclude_sites list.

The below URL deleted although the root domain of it is not store in the exclude_sites list.

ithazhtntr.media/kz7oc4f/sump-pump-alarm-amazon.html

I guess it only deleted because it consist of amazon in the URL. Which is not what I wanted. If its not the root domain or subdomain, I want to keep that URL.

Comment: My apologies for making the question confusing to you. The solution you shared on the first ocassion, actually helped me to overcome my problem. I can tweak the rest on my end. Than you once again.